# railstutorial how to add log out function and return to home page

Tags: railstutorial.org

I'm struggling through chapters 8 and 9 and was wondering how to change the behavior when user 1 tries to access https://rails-tutorial-rxyz.c9users.io/users/**2**/edit  directly.  The current behavior is to keep the user logged in and redirect to the home page.

I wanted to log_out and redirect to the home page.  I'm able to log_out but I keep getting redirected to the log_in page instead of the home page

Comment: Provided workspace doesn't have any project. https://rails-tutorial-rxyz.c9users.io/users/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

the

```
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
```

causes the problem.  If we edit:

```
def logged_in_user
```

by changing the flash message and redirecting to root_url it all works.

I placed the destroy function in sessions_helper so it would be available everywhere and then added destroy to the correct_user function.